# Rails 2 - Absolute of money

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2, currency

How to get absolute value of money?
e.g:

```
-2.to_money.? = 2.to_money
 2.to_money.? = 2.to_money
```

I have an attribute **total_price**, which may be positive or negative. I want to calculate the absolute value of total_price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now an absolute value method built-in to the Money::Arithmetic module:

```
2.to_money.abs == #<Money fractional:200 currency:USD> # true
-2.to_money.abs == #<Money fractional:200 currency:USD> # true
```

Answer (score 7):

Try taking the absolute value before converting to money.

`2.abs.to_money`

Comment: Thanks.According to my requirements, I'll have to do `total_price.cents.abs.to_money`. is there any other way?

Comment: I suppose you could monkey patch or extend the money class to add the needed function, but that seems like a lot of work, and a really bad idea.